# spark from scala 2.10.4 to 2.11

Tags: scala, eclipse-plugin, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to work with SparkSQL with tables which are more than 22 columns wide.

It seems that Scala 2.11 solves the issue.

Any help on how upgrading and possibly working cross versions?
I am using the Scala IDE in eclipse but because of problems with SchemaRDD I am ok at moving to Intellij IDEA.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not just try it and see if something breaks? The changes from 2.10 to 2.11 are relatively tiny. If you're using SBT, it's probably just a matter of changing the value of `scalaVersion` in your build file. Serialization compatibility is broken, if you need to read objects you've previously unmarshalled using the built-in serialization. But without knowing all of the libraries and features you're using in your project, it's impossible for anyone else to answer for you.

Comment: I really don't think that Spark will work with Scala 2.11 . This is why... Spark team explicitly suggests using Scala 2.10 . First of all... you will need to compile Spark against scala 2.11 ... If that works... ( with some miracle ).. then you can use that in  your Scala 2.11 project.

Answer (score 1):

In [Spark building documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-for-scala-211) there is the section about building Spark with Scala 2.11. However, the instruction can miss one step - look at [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685821/compile-spark-for-scala-2-11?rq=1).

Anyway, according to the documentation Scala 2.11 is not yet fully supported:

> Spark does not yet support its JDBC component for Scala 2.11.