# Compile Spark for Scala 2.11

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When compiling Spark with Scala 2.11 we get errors associated with spark-sql.

```
build/mvn -Dscala-2.11 -DskipTests clean package
```

The Spark build docs say: *Spark does not yet support its JDBC component for Scala 2.11.*

There has to be a way to compile without this.

**How do I compile Spark for Scala 2.11?**

Answer (score 4):

Before build run:

```
./dev/change-scala-version.sh 2.11
```

to change the Scala version. Strangely, this is not mentioned in the docs.

Additionally the error probably isn't related to spark-sql directly but rather some dependency that was compiled with Scala 2.10.